# :first-of-type doesn't work the way it should

Tags: html, css

I'm having trouble understanding why :first-of-type class works for all types, not just the first one. Here's my example code

```
**<style>
    .garden ol:first-of-type li {
        color: green;
    }
</style>**


<ul class="garden">
    <div>Garden</div>
    <li>Fruit:
        <ol>
            <li>One</li>
            <li>Two</li>
            <li>Three</li>
        </ol>
    </li>
    <li>Vegies:
        <ol>
            <li>One</li>
            <li>Two</li>
            <li>Three</li>
        </ol>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The result is that both OLs are colored in green.
If I try using :nth-of-type(1) - nothing is colored
If I try using :nth-of-type(2) - both OLs are colored again

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both `ol` elements are the first of their type (`ol`) inside their respective parent elements (two different `li` elements).

If you are trying to target the `ol` inside the first `li` inside the `ul` then you can use that `li` since it is the first of its type.

```
.gardern > li:first-of-type li
```

---

Note that `div` elements are *not* allowed to be children of `ul` elements.